# WorkAround for PHP PDO(with libpq V 9.1.4) binding for use of CITEXT?

Tags: postgresql, php, citext

The scenario

Two systems(not server) running PHP and PostgreSQL with the following versions

- ### Fedora 15:

  > #### PHP
  >
  > PHP 5.3.13 (cli) (built: May  9 2012 14:38:35)
  >  
  >   Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
  >  
  >   Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
  >  
  >   **pdo_pgsql**
  >   PostgreSQL(libpq) Version     9.0.7
  >   Module version    1.0.2
  >
  > ---
  >
  > #### PostgreSQL
  >
  > PostgreSQL 9.1.4
  >   With CITEXT extension enabled.
- ### ArchLinux:

  > #### PHP
  >
  > PHP 5.4.6 (cli) (built: Aug 16 2012 12:50:09)
  >   Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
  >   Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
  >   **pdo_pgsql**
  >   PostgreSQL(libpq) Version     9.1.4
  >   Module version    1.0.2
  >
  > ---
  >
  > #### PostgreSQL
  >
  > PostgreSQL 9.1.4
  >   With CITEXT extension enabled.

---

when a simple query such as

```
select column1 from schema1.table1 where column1= ?
```

Where column1 is of the type CITEXT, is executed through PHP PDO

- On Fedora with PHP 5.3.13,libpq 9.0.7, the query performs as expected with CITEXT(a *case insensitive* search occurs).
- On ArchLinux with PHP 5.4.6,libpq 9.1.4, the query does not perform as expected with CITEXT(a *case sensitive* search occurs).

I am guessing the newer version of PHP PDO libs are doing something similar to this:

```
select column1 from schema1.table1 where column1= 'value'::text;
```

during binding.

- Am I right?
- Is there a workaround? Otherwise, the use of CITEXT as a column data type to gain the advantage of case insensitive search is useless when using newer versions of PDO.

---

#### Update

#### After turning statement level logging on, on ArchLinux with PHP 5.4.6,libpq 9.1.4 :

```
LOG:  execute pdo_stmt_00000001: select column1 from schema1.table1 where column1 = $1
DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'value'
LOG:  statement: DEALLOCATE pdo_stmt_00000001
```

where the actual value of the column `column1` is `VALUE`.

Still comes back with 0 elements.

When the statement

```
select column1 from schema1.table1 where column1 = 'value';
```

is executed directly on the `PSQL` prompt comes back with a single row.

```
 column1  
---------
  VALUE
 (1 row)
```

So, the type casting does not take place! I still am not able to understand the behaviour of `PDO`/`postgresql`.

---

#### Update 2012-08-27 16:15:43.669142+00 (UMT + 0)

#### After trying to directly execute a query without preparing a statement.

Here is the code that was used to test :

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('pgsql:dbname=database1;user=user;password=pass;host=localhost');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT column1 from schema1.column1 where column1 = 'value'::citext ";
    $retval=$db->query($sql);
    foreach ($retval as $row) {
        print $row['uname'] . '<br>';
    }
}catch (PDOException $PDOerr) {
    echo 'An error occured : <br>';
    var_dump($PDOerr);
    exit;
    //some thing went wrong while performing the action on db.
    }
```

I get the error :

```
object(PDOException)#10 (8) { ["message":protected]=> string(211) "SQLSTATE[42704]: \
Undefined object: 7 ERROR: type "citext" does not exist LINE 1: ...
```

I do not understand why `citext` is not getting detected! 
When the statement is executed directly on the `PSQL` prompt, everything works fine as mentioned above.

Comment: Your updates make me think this is a permissions issue. Are you using the same user via PHP as via psql?

Comment: Incidentally have you tried `select column1 from schema1.table1 where column1= 'value'::text;` from psql? I think you will find it casts the value right back to `citext` implicitly.

Comment: @JackDouglas both the installations have the same user and same grant permissions

Comment: @JackDouglas Yes, I have.. it works as excepted. CITEXT does gets recognized as a valid datatype. And the result is a single row.

Comment: can you narrow the problem down, eg by changing your query to `select column1 from schema1.table1 order by column1 limit 1;` and comparing?

Comment: @JackDouglas  
It was a search path problem for the user I was trying to login as. I am guessing I had created the user when I had done a session-wise `set search_path` to some other schema and instead of the default '"$user",public' it was set to the other schema. The user did not have any access to `public schema` at all. Thanks to `Daniel Vérité` for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locate the namespace inside which the `citext` type resides:

```
select nspname from pg_type t join pg_namespace n
  on n.oid=t.typnamespace where typname='citext';
```

Prepend that namespace (normally, 'public', but it might be different in your case and it might explain the problem) to the cast to `citext`:

```
$sql = "SELECT column1 from schema1.column1 where column1 = 'value'::public.citext";
```

If that solves the problem but in a way you find inelegant, you might reconsider how you're using schemas and `search_path`: make sure that all your custom types are accessible no matter what.

Comment: It was a search path problem for the user I was trying to login as. I am guessing I had created the user when I had done a session-wise `set search_path` to some other schema and instead of the default '"$user",public' it was set to the other schema.

The user did not have any access to public schema at all. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: BTW, used `ALTER ROLE user SET search_path TO "$user",public;` to set the search path. Although, $user is useless as I do not have any schema named after the current users.